# How do I acquire Outfit Vouchers?

Tags: monster-hunter-rise

Outfit Vouchers are used to craft layered armour, and you require a *lot* of them to craft layered versions of the higher tiered armor. Fugen the Elder gives you 3 of them, but how do I acquire more? I've already received  one from a quest, but I'm wondering if quests are the only way to get them. Even if they are, I'm curious if all quests have a chance to drop them, or if only higher HR quests do.

**How do I acquire Outfit Vouchers?**

Answer (score 1):

From perusing some Reddit threads and looking at game guides and articles, it appears like you can have a chance to get Outfit Vouchers from certain **HR 7☆** quests. There was also a source claiming they come from HR 8+ hunts, but no other source could verify that yet.

Specifically, one person writing for Gamepur acquired them from an HR 7 [Almudron](https://monsterhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Almudron) hunt, in the bonus quest rewards. They appear to always be located in the **Quest Bonus Rewards** section of your rewards, and are a Rarity 4 item with the description:

> A ticket needed to forge layered armor. For the fashion-conscious hunter.

([Relevant article](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/how-to-get-outfit-vouchers-in-monster-hunter-rise)) ([Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/n038ii/do_we_have_information_on_how_to_get_outfit/))

[image]